# Update takes too much time at Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I use oracle 10. 
I have update statement like that :

```
update table1 t1 
   set v_value=(select v_value 
                from table2 t2 
                where t2.user_id=t1.user_id  
                  and t2.item_id=t1.item_id  )
```

It works but takes too much time. How can I optimize it ?

Comment: What are your indexes? How many records are there in the table?

Comment: In addition to @Ben's questions, what is the query plan?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try a merge statement:

```
merge into table1 t1
using
(
   select user_id,
          item_id,
          v_value
   from table2
) t2 ON (t1.user_id = t1.user_id and t1.item_id = t1.item_id)
when matched then update
  set v_value = t2.v_value;
```

(you might need to check the syntax, there were same changes to which parts in a MERGE are mandatory and which not between 10 and 11 - haven't used 10g for a long time)

Comment: If you don't have an index on (user_id, item_id) you should create one. Will probably make things even faster. Might be also worthwhile trying an index on table2(user_id, item_id, v_value) to allow for an index only retrieval in the inner select.

Comment: That's really bad advice here. Simply changing SQL statements without any proper analysis. This no engineering approach at all.

Comment: @steve: I have seen a MERGE out-perform an UPDATE with a (co-related) sub-query very often. And please notice that I said: "*try* a merge". The engineering cannot be done through a forum like this (I don't have the OPs data or database). It has to be done through the person running the statements.

Comment: I don't agree. The first step would be to get an execution plan with stats and if more detail is required a 10053 trace. What you are recommending is simply guessing. It is no approach to performance tuning.

Answer (score -3):

It is almost impossible to tune a statement just by looking at it.
get explain plan, it will tell you if you are using a full table scan (set autotrace on).
I also suggest to use a free tool, i just posted - odbtools.com. It allows you to analyze your statement and generate the explain plan, It will show you if you have a full table scan and your select part doesn't use an index.

Comment: You properly disclosed your affiliation with this product in this answer, but I had to remove your other answer because it looked like astroturfing. I recommend reading [these guidelines for self-promotion here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/59302/135615).